# Delegate on a property

Tags: .net, vb.net, properties, delegates

I've seen some workaround with c# but I'm using vb.net, and I can't call a delegate for a property, at elast I doN,t know how, and no one seems to have a straight forward answer

So if someone do : How to add or create a delegate for a property

Comment: Can you illustrate what you're looking for in VB.NET by showing us the C# workaround?

Comment: yes give me a minute

Edit
I don't find it :S

Comment: A delegate needs a target method.  So write one that returns the property.  Make it compact with a lambda.

Answer (score 0):

For a property called `PropertyName` of type `TProp` the underlying implementation is 2 methods:

- `function get_PropertyName() as TProp`
- `sub set_PropertyName(value as TProp)`

---

Here's an example for a string property:

```
Public Delegate Function StringGetter() As String
Public Delegate Sub StringSetter(value As String)

Class Test
    Public Property MyProp As String
End Class

Public Sub Main()

    Dim testObj As New Test With {.MyProp = "Hello"}

    Dim getter = [Delegate].CreateDelegate(GetType(StringGetter), testObj, "get_MyProp")
    If CType(getter.DynamicInvoke(), String) <> "Hello" Then Throw New Exception("get failed")

    Dim setter = [Delegate].CreateDelegate(GetType(StringSetter), testObj, "set_MyProp")
    setter.DynamicInvoke("Hello2")
    If testObj.MyProp <> "Hello2" Then Throw New Exception("set failed")

End Sub
```